# Multiple Travelling salesman with given deadline (single depot)

Tags: optimization, graph-theory, traveling-salesman, glpk, mathprog

I have a problem that related to Travelling Salesman Problem with multiple salesmen. I have a list of cities to visit from an initial location,and the all salesmen start and end at the same places .Each salesman have to visit cities and come back to its initial location within given deadline (deadline for distance).The goal is to minimize travelling distance for all saleman.

I tried to solve the problem using MathProg language in GLPK. But i could not come up with good solution (Subtour not properly eliminated,feasible solution not obtained...) .If any body solve this types of problem, I need advise from them...(How to solve my problem and obtain result for this problem)

Comment: This is the classical vehicle routing problem (VRP). There are a lot of heuristics and exact algorithms. It generally is not solved directly as a math programming problem because of the exponential size. Some Googling should get you started.

Comment: @ grendelsdad Thank you for your reply.Can you give me some simple hints from where i can start?Actually i am new in that area.So,any recommendation from you helps me much.Thanks advance..

Comment: try http://neo.lcc.uma.es/vrp/.

Comment: You should look into Genetic algorithms for an efficient way find good solutions to the VRP.

Comment: @grendelsdad this link helps me much.thank you.

Comment: @Mark-Thank you for your reply...any useful link helps me much..